# PDFs want to scale down

Tags: pdftex, pdf, paper-size, adobe

I'm not sure if this is a TeX related question at all or rather a general problem with Adobe reader, or Windows, or printer drivers, or whatever else is involved.

When I create PDF files with pdflatex in A4 paper size and print them to my A4 printer from Adobe reader, there are several options available for "Page scaling", such as "None", "Fit to printable area", and "Shrink to printable area". Since the document and paper size ar both A4, one might expect that all three options result in printout at original size, especially if there is a thick white margin and nothing interferes with technical printing problems at the paper boundary, say. However, the fit/shrink options both cause a scale factor of 94% and one has to be careful to select the "None" option in order to obtain correct output.

Minimal (with respect to pdf content) example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null
\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to set something in my TeX files such that the pdf files produced are "aware" that there is enough white margin and that no 94% scaling is needed? (Alternatively, I might produce page sizes 6% smaller than A4, but would consider that counterproductive and ridiculuous)

Comment: Please show us a minimal document code which leads to this error for you. It sounds like a driver issue (off-topic) but let us have a look on your documentclass and `hyperref` setting. Maybe there are culprit parts in it (which you might find when doing the MWE). Thanks.

Comment: I've always found really peculiar that Adobe Reader thinks A4 paper doesn't fit in A4 paper and wants to scale it down. I don't think it's a TeX and friends problem, but just Adobe's.

Comment: The 94% scaling is a function of your printer's margins. Adobe Reader sees an A4 (or US letter, or whatever) page size and wants to fit that page size into the printable area on the sheet (*inside* the margins). So if you know you have an A4 page with acceptable margins for the printer, just remove any scaling.

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None}`

Comment: @Thérèse doesn't help.

Comment: My hopes were that one of those PDF boxes (MediaBox, CropBox, Bleedbox, TrimBox, ArtBox, WhateverBox) just might need a kick in their butt.

Comment: You're missing an `\usepackage{geometry}`. Otherwise the size of the PDF can well be letter.

Comment: `\hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None}` works fine for me: In the print dialog the "don't scale" option is then selected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think the option that is selected in the print dialog is simple the one you used last. I'd be more interested in a feature that would cause no scaling even if I selct "scale to paper" because the driver should notice that there is sufficient margin. This may hoever be a dream ...

Comment: No, the option really change the default dialog. I tested it. And I don't know how the driver should notice that there is a margin: It doesn't look at the content.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think this might rather be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388761/mac-pdf-preview-wants-to-scale-down

Answer (score 3):

If I run `pdfinfo -box` on a PDF file generated by `pdftex`, I get the following information:

```
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.15
CreationDate:   Mon Oct  6 16:01:48 2014
ModDate:        Mon Oct  6 16:01:48 2014
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
CropBox:            0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
File size:      58874 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

When I check a PDF exported from TextEdit, I get

```
Title:          ***
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         ***
Creator:        TextEdit
Producer:       Mac OS X 10.9.2 Quartz PDFContext
CreationDate:   Mon Oct  6 14:10:45 2014
ModDate:        Mon Oct  6 14:10:45 2014
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
CropBox:            0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
File size:      16393 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

The only possible problem might be the page width, which is 595.276 in the former case, 595 in the latter.

Now `\pdfpagewidth` is set to `597.50787pt`, which corresponds to `595.27559bp` and this explains the shown value of `595.276`. If we convert this into millimeters, we get

```
597.50787*25.4/72.27 = 209.99999
```

but converting `595.276bp` to millimeters gives

```
595.276*25.4/72 = 210.00014
```

I don't think that a surplus of less than 150nm (nanometers) should trigger a size reduction of 6% “to fit”. Even if 595.28 is used, we have

```
595.28*25.4/72 = 210.00156
```

but, again, a surplus of less than 2µm (micrometers) doesn't seem sufficient for pushing Adobe Reader into thinking that the page “doesn't fit”.

The conversion of `595bp` into millimeters is

```
595*25.4/72 = 209.90278
```

which is short of 210mm by sligthly more than 0.04%, while 210.00156mm is about 0.001% more than 210mm.

Nothing will convince me that the computations made by Adobe Reader are so accurate that a difference of *less* than 0.001% forces shrinking.

Comment: Nice investigations, but behind all that I kind of lost the point of your answer. What exactly are these boxes and what does the output of `pdfinfo` tell us?  Why do you compare to a PDF from TextEdit? Does it not show the weird behavior in AR?

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect that at least one of the boxes should not start at '0.00 0.00', because of the margin.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, a PDF originated by exporting instead of printing doesn't cause Adobe Reader to try shrinking.

Comment: @egreg Oh, interesting. So it seems it *is* possible to put the information that shrinking is a bad idea somewhere. Admittedly, I just tried the same with a pdf export (from Word 2010 under Windows 2008) and *that* showed the same 94% problem. Can you somehow upload an A4 pdf that does not wnat to shrink so that I can test it on my system?

Comment: SOLUTION: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232718/4736