# Mac PDF preview wants to scale down

Tags: xetex, pdf

When I render a document with XeLaTeX on A4 paper and try to print it with the Mac PDF Preview app, scaling is automatically set to 96% to make the document fit the paper.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

When I open A4-sized PDFs created with other software and print them with PDF Preview, no scaling is applied (100%).

Neither of the two techniques in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232712/prevent-scaling-of-printout-of-pdf-without-using-hyperref) help.

Answer (score 2):

Mac preview has the annoying habit to automatically scale down pages. To switch this off, enter

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview PVImagePrintingScaleMode 0
```

in terminal.

*In case you understand German, more details can be found at https://blogs.fau.de/faumac/de-aktivieren-der-automatischen-druckskalierung-von-apples-vorschau-app/*

Comment: That doesn't help if you're producing documents for _other_ people to view. My solution produces documents that aren't scaled on anybody's Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This prevents the Mac PDF Preview app from offering any scaling:

```
\usepackage[paperheight=842bp,paperwidth=595bp]{geometry}
```

---

I uncompressed the resulting PDFs with `pdftk test.pdf output uc.pdf uncompress`.

It turned out that `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` leads to `/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]`, which causes the Preview app to offer to scale down to 96% by default.

Next I tried `\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm]{geometry}`, which leads to the exact same result.

Then I tried `\usepackage[paperheight=296mm,paperwidth=209mm]{geometry}`. This gives `/MediaBox [0 0 592.44 839.06]`, but the Preview app still wants to scale down to 96%, **even though the document is actually 1mm smaller** than the A4 paper to be printed on!

I found **only one format that leads to no scaling** and that is `/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]`, that is in LaTeX:

```
\usepackage[paperheight=842bp,paperwidth=595bp]{geometry}
```