# Prevent scaling down when printing ConTeXt produced pdf on macOS

Tags: luatex, context

There is this annoying thing that **Preview of macOS scales down the printout** of XeTeX and ConTeXt produced pdfs by default even though paper size matches.

It's been discussed here
[Mac PDF preview wants to scale down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388761/mac-pdf-preview-wants-to-scale-down/388763)
and there [PDFs want to scale down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204794/pdfs-want-to-scale-down).

Which fixed it for me for several years in XeTeX was using the geometry package with paperwidth and paperheight specified in bp as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388762

Now, that I'm shifting to **ConTeXt** for a project, the issue comes up again. I haven't found a fix so far. Obviously I tried setting dimensions in bp again:

```
\definepapersize[fixed][width=595bp, height=842bp]
\setuppapersize[fixed][fixed]
```

I also tried:

```
\paperwidth595bp
\paperheight842bp
```

While that changes dimensions of the MediaBox to 595pt and 842pt, which was seen as the culprit in the answers linked above, Preview still scales down by default :(

**Any ideas how to fix this annoying thing in LuaTeX and ConTeXt?**

*Background: I think it's actually more than annoying. I use TeX and friends for a reason. I want my documents to look good. If I prepare e.g. a resume the recruiter might print it out without noticing it's been scaled down. After all that may reflect bad on me for using wide margins, which in turn totally contradicts the purpose of using TeX in the first place.*

Comment: This is a viewer issue. Use another one. In its printing dialog select something like "Page Scaling=None" or similar.

Comment: As Alex mentions this is a viewer issue, the default is always to scale. Quite strange that for example AR may scale down an A4 even if it is printing on A4.

Comment: If it were a viewer issue why would it work just fine in XeTeX using `\usepackage[paperheight=842bp,paperwidth=595bp]{geometry}`?

Comment: Viewer issues are not necessarily off topic if there is a programmatic way to solve them.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in Mac OS X Preview, because ConTeXt defines the paper size correctly according to ISO and the PDF has `/MediaBox [0 0 595.27559 841.88976]` which is even a bit smaller than A4 (should be `/MediaBox [0 0 595.3 841.9]`).  Therefore voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Also this is probably a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/keep-preview-from-autoresizing-print-output